# when i save that in database, field password is empty in database,

Tags: php, database, laravel

[image]

```
protected function create(array $data)
 {
     return Customer::create([
        'nama_customer' => $data['nama'],
        'password' =>bcrypt($data['password']),
        'kontak' => $data['kontak'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
      ])
  }
```

I want to make a multi auth laravel, but when i save register data in database, field password is empty in database, can anyone help me to fix it ?

Comment: You really should paste in actual code. Plus, you didn't actually ask a question. Try again.

Comment: @Difster i already write the code,

Comment: Is your password in the fillable array of your customer model? If not Laravel will ignore the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be any number of things. Maybe your password field is named differently in the database, maybe it has the wrong data type or data length. Check those things.